# Vectorization in R of a Complex Algorithm

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

My code calls the below function many times. I've used Rprof to find out that it's taking up 1/3 of the execution time.

I've heard that R can be made faster by vectorization. However, the algorithm that I am using accesses two indexes in two different lists, so I don't see how any of the *ply functions would work.

Is there anything else that could be done to optimize this?

n is an integer, u and v are lists of complex numbers

```
psi <- function(n, u, v)
{
    psi = complex(real = 0, imaginary = 0)

    for (i in 1 : (n - 1))
    {
        for (j in (i + 1) : n)
        {
            psi = psi + log(u[i] * v[j] - u[j] * v[i])
        }
    }

    return (psi * 3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If i read your code correctly, for the case `n=4` your summation boils down to

```
log(u[1]*v[2] - u[2]*v[1]) +
log(u[1]*v[3] - u[3]*v[1]) +
log(u[1]*v[4] - u[4]*v[1]) +

log(u[2]*v[3] - u[3]*v[2]) +
log(u[2]*v[4] - u[4]*v[2]) +

log(u[3]*v[4] - u[4]*v[3])
```

which is really just all possible combinations of n choose 2. You can create such a list of indexes with `combn()`.

```
psi <- function(n,u,v) {
    mx <- function(p) {a<-p[1]; b<-p[2]; log(u[a]*v[b]-u[b]*v[a])}
    sum(combn(n,2, FUN=mx)) * 3
}
```

Here the inner `mx` function takes care of the calculation for each pair of indices. This seems to remarkably faster. I guess you want to make sure they get the same results. I had a difficult time generating test input that didn't make the `log` angry.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following might solve your problem. I chose this method of expression because I think it is very transparent given what you've already done. Essentially I've just generated a vector of i, and j in advance and used them just as you have but simultaneously as vectors (copied and pasted your equation).

```
psi <- function(n,u,v) {
    j <- combn(n, 2) #I'll overwrite j later to conserve memory
    i <- j[1,]
    j <- j[2,]
    sum(log(u[i] * v[j] - u[j] * v[i])) * 3
}
```

This will be very much faster than your loops as long as n is not a very large number because it must generate and maintain in memory the entire combination set that you're generating with your your loops all at once. But at the point this would break down you're into a long calculation either way.

To show the equivalence consider the results of comparing your methods of generating your indices and the present one.

```
n <- 5
combn(n, 2)

for (i in 1 : (n - 1))
{
    for (j in (i + 1) : n)
    {
        print(c(i, j))
    }
}
```